# How to subtract values of specific columns using values in other columns as a key

Tags: r, tidyverse

How can I subtract values in the last three columns using `c` as a reference (post-pre) and `b` and `d` as keys?

#### input

```
df1 <- tribble(
  ~a, ~b, ~c, ~d, ~e, ~f, ~g,
  "1396-006_post_B", "1396-006", "post", "B", 18, 16, 0,
  "1396-006_post_L", "1396-006", "post", "L", 7, 15, 0,
  "1396-006_pre_B", "1396-006", "pre", "B", 16, 9, 0,
  "1396-006_pre_L", "1396-006", "pre", "L", 2, 1, 0,
  "1396-053_post_B", "1396-053", "post", "B", 25, 58, 0,
  "1396-053_pre_B", "1396-053", "pre", "B", 24, 27, 0
)
```

#### output

```
1396-006_B  2 7 0
1396-006_L  5 14  0
1396-053_B  1 31  0
```

#### tried

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(b, d) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(diff))%>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but I went with

```
(df1 
    %>% group_by(b,d) 
    %>% arrange(c)
    %>% summarise_at(vars(e:g),funs(-1*diff(.)))
)
```

- using `summarise_at()` rather than `mutate_at()`
- use `-1*diff(.)` to get the sign right, and `arrange(c)` to make sure the order is correct. Alternatively you could use (1) `arrange(desc(c))` plus `funs(diff)` or  (2) something that explicitly refers to pre/post, e.g. `funs(.[c=="post"]-.[c=="pre"])` (I think the latter would be more explicit)
- perhaps the most principled way to do this would be to `spread()` out to separate pre/post columns, then compute the difference ... but I'm not really sure how to get differences of multiple, matched pairs of columns ...

Comment: But I think here you are not using `pre` `post` keys? For example, if `c` column is not ordered the results will be different, yes?

Comment: I think here `arrange(c)` is better but yes this is a good idea but not a perfect approach. This works `df1  %>%
  arrange(c)%>% 
  group_by(b,d)%>%
  summarise_at(vars(e:g),funs(-1*diff(.)))`

Comment: This is too slow for a big matrix(>20k columns)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the data properly, could be done using reshape2 library and altering the key:

```
library(reshape2)

df1 <- mutate(df1, key = paste(b,d, sep = "-"))
df2 <- dcast(melt(df1), key ~ c + variable)
df2 %>% mutate(diff_e = post_e - pre_e,
                diff_f = post_f - pre_f,
                diff_g = post_g - pre_g)
```

Gives case-wise observations for pre, post and diff:

```
           key   post_e post_f post_g pre_e pre_f pre_g diff_e diff_f diff_g
  1 1396-006-B     18     16      0    16     9     0      2      7      0
  2 1396-006-L      7     15      0     2     1     0      5     14      0
  3 1396-053-B     25     58      0    24    27     0      1     31      0
```